# The data factory event triggers aren't always running

Tags: azure-data-factory

I created an event trigger based on a file landing on my storage account. However, it runs one day and does not the next. In the last 10 days since this event trigger was created, the event has not triggered the pipeline on three days. Could you please let me know what could be possibly going wrong here?

[image]

I recreated the trigger and also tried to stop and start, but the issue still exists.

Comment: The container value must begin and end with "/", so the container value should be "/techedge/"

Answer (score 0):

There could be several reasons why the event trigger is not working as expected.

- One possible reason could be that the file is not landing on that specific folder of storage account with the extension you mentioned in the trigger on the days when the event trigger is not working.
- Agreed with Joel Cochran the container name should be in `/ContainerName/` format so that It can be able to go inside child directory.
  [image]
- Another possible reason could be that the event trigger is not configured correctly (Naming issues). You can check the configuration of the event trigger and ensure that it is set up correctly. (In data preview section of trigger, you can see if it is taking correct data or not.)
- If still not working you can check for logs with diagnostic settings look for any error is coming or not.
  [image]

Comment: Hi Pratik, I can confirm below -
1. File is la

Comment: Hi Pratik, 
I can confirm below -

1. There is no issue with file landing, I can confirm file lands on the directory I mentioned in my screenshot with extension as .csv

2. Container name is valid. What is happening here is after we save the trigger the backslashes are hidden, when I try to edit I can see the backslashes so this is also not an issue here.

Comment: 3. I can't notice any issues here either, using the data preview I can see all the files in my container as I mentioned.

So it's strange what is happening here and can't find a way to get this fixed. I still have this issue where the trigger don't fire but as soon as I stop and start the trigger it is running for 3-4 days and then stops again.